# R Error with neural network caret parameter tuning

Tags: r, neural-network, r-caret

I'm working on tuning parameters for a neural network exercise on the Boston dataset. I have been getting a persistent error:

> Error: The tuning parameter grid should have columns size, decay

The following is the set up of my Caret tuning:

```
caret_control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                       number = 10,
                       repeats = 3)

caret_grid <- expand.grid(batch_size=seq(60,120,20),
                      dropout=0.5,
                      size=100,
                      decay = 0,
                      lr=2e-6,
                      activation = "relu")

caret_t <- train(medv ~ ., data = chasRad, 
             method = "nnet", 
             metric="RMSE",
             trControl = caret_control, 
             tuneGrid = caret_grid,
             verbose = FALSE)
```

Here chasRad is a 12x506 matrix. Could anyone help on fixing the error that seems triggered by the expanded grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting should be interpreted as:

"The tuning parameter grid should *ONLY* have columns size, decay".

You're passing in four additional parameters that `nnet` can't tune in `caret`. For a full list of parameters that are tunable, run `modelLookup(model = 'nnet')`.

To tune only `size` and `decay`, replace your `caret_grid` with:

```
caret_grid <- expand.grid(size=seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1),
                      decay = seq(from = 0.1, to = 0.5, by = 0.1))
```

and your code will run.

Comment: There are some neural network models via `keras` that `caret` can use with some of those parameters. See `?models` or the `caret` website.